# Audio not working on Dell XPS 7590

Tags: debian, drivers, audio

Just installed Debian on my Dell XPS 7590 and can't seem to get it to recognize the PCI audio controller. Its audio device is listed as `00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)`. I've tried installing a number of driver packages including firmware-misc-nonfree and firmware-intel-sound, nothing has worked so far. If I try listing playback devices with `aplay -l` it only returns HDMI devices.

Hoping somebody has some insight, please let me know if there's any more information that would be useful and thanks.

Edit: Output of `inix --admin -A` is:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:a348 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-37-generic
```

Comment: What you should be looking at are the kernel modules; `snd`, `snd_timer`, `snd_pcm`, `snd_hda_core`, `snd_hda_codec`, `snd_intel_dspcfg`, `snd_hda_intel`. Possibly not all of them, but equally possibly. others not listed.

Comment: All of the modules you listed appear to be loaded already, along with quite a few others. Where should I go from here to continue troubleshooting?

Comment: Start delving through the system logs. It may be that your kernel does not support Cannon Lake.

Comment: I have the same soundcard on a different laptop, it worked fine out of the box for me on manjaro but see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MSI_GE75_Raider_8SX#Audio you might have more problems with it. Only thing I can suggest though is to try installing sof-firmware.

Comment: You should provide output of `inxi --admin -A` if you want more help tho.  You're just not providing enough information, the card should use snd_hda_intel driver, is it actually using that driver?

Comment: @Cestarian Done, output is shown above. Looks like it's using snd_hda_intel?

Comment: Also I tried with sof-firmware, it didn't seem to do anything.